# Automatizar cálculo de snow cover con imágenes Sentinel 2 en R

Tags: r, bucles

Estoy trabajando en temas de nieve con imágenes Sentinel-2. He conseguido realizar un script que me calcule el snow cover para las imágenes Sentinel una a una. Lo hace acorde a los parámetros recogidos en Gascoin et al. 2019: NDSI > 0.4 y banda del rojo > 0.1. Me gustaría que este proceso se realizase de manera automática para todos los archivos de un directorio. Imagino que será a través de un bucle, pero no sé muy bien como abordarlo.
El código que he utilizado es el siguiente:

```
#Packages needed
library(RStoolbox)
library(raster)
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
library(rgdal)

setwd('/Desktop/images/s2') #Working directory

sentinel <-"20170225T105021_20170225T105020_T30TYN.tif" #image

swir <- raster(sentinel, band = 12) # Swir band
green <- raster(sentinel, band = 3) # green band
red <- raster(sentinel, band = 4) #red band

ndsi <- (green-swir)/(green+swir) # NDSI calculation 
ndsi[ndsi>1] <- 1; ndsi[ndsi< (-1)] <- -1 # rescale for avoiding outliers

r <- stack(ndsi, red) # layerstack with ndsi and red band

snow_reclass <- function(x1,x2) { #reclass function with snow cover paranmeters
  ifelse( x1 > 0.4 & x2 > 0.1, 1, 0)
}

snowcover <- overlay(r, fun=snow_reclass) #Apply the function to the layer stack (red and NDSI)

writeRaster(snowcover, "snowcover170225.tiff", #Export the result
            format="GTiff",
            overwrite=TRUE,
            NAflag=-9999)
```

Answer (score 0):

Efectivamente es por medio de un bucle, están los bucles implícitos, por ejemplo los  de las funciones `*apply()` y los explícitos mediante un `for`, `while` o  `repeat`.  La idea es recorrer la lista de archivos de un carpeta determinada, por ejemplo:

```
for (file in list.files(pattern = "*.tif", include.dirs=FALSE)) {
  print(file)
}
```

Lo que faltaría es encapsular todo tu código en una función:

```
process_a_file <- function(sentinel) {

  swir <- raster(sentinel, band = 12) # Swir band
  green <- raster(sentinel, band = 3) # green band
  red <- raster(sentinel, band = 4) #red band
  
  ndsi <- (green-swir)/(green+swir) # NDSI calculation 
  ndsi[ndsi>1] <- 1; ndsi[ndsi< (-1)] <- -1 # rescale for avoiding outliers
  
  r <- stack(ndsi, red) # layerstack with ndsi and red band
  
  snow_reclass <- function(x1,x2) { #reclass function with snow cover paranmeters
    ifelse( x1 > 0.4 & x2 > 0.1, 1, 0)
  }
  
  snowcover <- overlay(r, fun=snow_reclass) #Apply the function to the layer stack (red and NDSI)
  
  out_filename <- paste0('snowcover', substr(ff, 19, 24), '.tiff')
  writeRaster(snowcover, out_filename, #Export the result
              format="GTiff",
              overwrite=TRUE,
              NAflag=-9999)
}
```

Nota: Revisa la forma que usé para construir el archivo de salida: `out_filename <- paste0('snowcover', substr(ff, 19, 24), '.tiff')`

Por último integramos todo:

```
setwd('/Desktop/images/s2') #Working directory
for (file in list.files(pattern = "*.*", include.dirs=FALSE)) {
  process_a_file(file)
}
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, Patricio!!! Un cordial saludo!!!!